# Mac Kiosk Mode API - Prevent Users from Quitting

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

I'm in the process of writing a Mac (10.6 / 10.7) application that authenticates users against an Active Directory domain before allowing them access to the computer (I'm told I can't allow users to log on via traditional log on services). I have the authentication code in place, and am now trying to make this login window fullscreen and unable to close.

Apple's Kiosk Mode API ([documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html)) seems like a great fit for this, and I've used it to bring the window fullscreen, disable the dock / menu bar / force quit, etc., all of which works fine. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to prevent users from simply CMD+Q'ing out of the application.

There's no point in a kiosk mode application with limitations when a user can just quit out of it, so I'm assuming I'm missing something. Below is an example of what I'm doing:

```
NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = 
NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar|NSApplicationPresentationHideDock|
NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication|
NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching|
NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu| NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit;

[NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
[[_window contentView] enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];
```

Result: Full screen window, no menu bar, no dock, can't force quit and can't CMD+Tab away from the screen. CMD+Q still quits the application.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW4

Comment: What did the trick @Blastfire?

Comment: You should either edit your own question with the correct solution and accept it as correct. Or accept the correct one, that way other people  can benefit from it

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing he found the same solution that I did, but since it isn't actually answered here I thought I'd detail it.

What you need to do is to implement the following NSApplicationDelegate method:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
```

And then return NSTerminateCancel here when your app is in Kiosk mode.