# Mac: lock user into app

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

I want to program a "distraction-free mode" for my Mac application. Is it possible to enter full-screen mode and prevent the user from switching to any other application actually locking her into the program (for example, for a given amount of time)?

Comment: not speaking from experience...but from logic this sounds like it would be extremely frowned upon by apple. would open up so many malicious uses.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use "Kiosk Mode": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434497/mac-kiosk-mode-api-prevent-users-from-quitting?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [kiosk mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html). The short version is that you can set `NSApplication.sharedApplication().presentationOptions`. You can mix and match options (within some rules), but one obvious set would mix `.HideDock`, `.HideMenuBar`, and `.DisableProcessSwitching`.

You can either manually size and position your app window to cover the full screen or you can call `enterFullScreenMode(_:withOptions:)` on a view to present in full-screen mode. For the latter, you can combine the setting of the presentation options with entering full-screen mode as documented in the kiosk mode tech note.

Comment: Would this prevent the use to Alt-Tab switch to other apps?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things that `.DisableProcessSwitching` does. Read the docs and make sure you use all of the options that seem appropriate.